# Writing through an API from a SQL Server trigger

Tags: .net, sql-server, post, sql-server-2012, http-post

I have been tasked with figuring out how to push data from a local SQL server database (db1) to a SQL database that is hosted by a third party (db2).
Simply put, we want to be able to create records in db2 as they are created in db1, as well as have db2 reflect any updates or deletes that have been made to db1 (CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE).  The third party has an API that we can apparently use to write to our data in db2.

I am familiar and experienced with setting up triggers to push data from one table to another *within* SQL server, but I have never tried to write to a table via an API. I am not very familiar with API's to begin with.

Has anyone else done something like this before?  If so, can you recommend any resources that may explain how to do it?  I am looking at using a CLR trigger, but I am not sure if this is the right path when trying to work with APIs.  Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that you write to another SQL Server or API directly from a trigger as that can cause the original write operations to hang until the remote server/API responds.  Rather I'd recommend that you use an asynchronous approach like Service Broker or CDC (Change Data Control).